# Session being cleared during paypal Express checkout

Tags: php, html, paypal, express-checkout

I am currently developing an E-Comm site that uses Paypals express check out system. The express checkout system works fine, I send the payments amount, the user logs in to confirm the shipping details, and returns back to my page where I confirm it and the payment is completed. The main issue I am having is that I have the username (email) saved in the session. Once the user clicks checkout with paypal and confirms his/her paypal account, my session is cleared. So I cannot keep a record of who purchased what item (unless I use the users paypals email address which could be different from the one the user used on my site).

So my question is, is there any way that I can preserve the session state throughout this confirmation action? Or is there another way to keep the users information? is this a documented problem (I have not seen it anywhere)?

If any more detail is required let me know.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, once the user leaves your domain the session will terminate.

Instead you can store the email address in a table before user leaves your site and pass the ID of the inserted record to paypal. As this ID is a custom field it will be returned in the call back url once the user completes the payment. You can get the ID from URL and retrieve the corresponding email from database.

Comment: Create a.session on your site, go to another site not on your domain stay there for few minutes and return to the page with session by typing its address in the address bar and hitting enter....

Answer (score 0):

Even if your PHP session didn't terminate (there is likely a different reason for it closing), it still isn't a good idea to depend on the session being unmodified between the time the user leaves for PayPal and returns. Consider a user with multiple tabs that starts poking around your website in another tab before finishing Express Checkout.

Instead, store everything that is important to your checkout completion in a database, and pass a unique identifier through the Express Checkout process via the [CUSTOM](http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide/Appx_fieldreference.html#2825815) or [INVNUM](http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide/Appx_fieldreference.html#2825844) parameters. Those will be juggled through the checkout process. Once the callback returns to your site, you can very easily identify which "incomplete" order in your database it is referring to and mark it "paid."

Comment: I tried to set the CUSTOM property, and the INVNUM property, but when I get to my confirmation page it says that the index does not exists. Is there anything special I need to do in order to access it?

Comment: Have you tried dumping the PayPal response with var_dump() to verify it's not in the reply by a similar name? If passed correctly in the call to SetExpressCheckout, it should be there. It looks like from EC v63 on, CUSTOM and INVNUM are deprecated in favor of PAYMENTREQUEST_n_CUSTOM and PAYMENTREQUEST_n_INVNUM. https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_SetExpressCheckout

Comment: I used print_r to display all the values inside the array that is returned to me, there is no instances of INVNUM or CUSTOM there.